# Discrete Fourier Transform and Fast Fourier Transform complexity

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-transform

So it is known that the complexity of DFT is $O(n^2)$ and of FFT is $O(nlog_2 n)$.

However in my material, it is stated that the worst-case complexity of DFT is $O(n^2)$ only if $n$ is a prime number. So I am wondering what difference $n$ makes if it is a prime, and what would the complexity be if it is not a prime number?

We know that FFT goes when $n = 2^k$, but an example is if $n=6$, this is not a prime number and there is no $k$ such that $n=2^k$, so what is the complexity in that case?

Comment: It meant the worst case of the FFT algorithm. See the case [$n=2^k$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm#The_radix-2_DIT_case). With a modification it works if $n = pq$. Otherwise we have some problems.

Comment: Note that the DFT is a mathematical transform, with no specification of how it is computed, hence saying $O(n^2)$ is meaningless. On the opposite, the FFT is an algorithm that implements the DTF and indeed has $n\log n$ complexity when $n$ is a power of $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magical characteristic of the Fast Fourier Transform is that it turns a product of factors in a sum of factors

$$N=p\cdot q\to (p+q)N$$
$$N=2^n\to (n\cdot 2)N=2N\log_2N$$
$$N=p^mq^nr^k\cdots\to(mp+nq+kr+\cdots)N$$

because the whole process can be decomposed as a sequence of stages of complexity $pN$ where $N$ is the number of coefficients and $p$ a factor of $N$.

Prime $N$ indeed make it quadratic $O(N^2)$.

Comment: But what if there is an $N$ which is not prime and it cannot be used with FFT?

Comment: @osk: composite numbers can be used with the FFT, I gave examples.